# wso2iot 3.1.0 install problems

Tags: mdm, wso2-iot

Clean install:

- Downloaded `wso2iot 3.1.0` from GitHub
- Downloaded `yajsw-stable-12.09`

Put them in one file (wso):

- Pointed `jdk1.7.0_75` for `JAVA_HOME`
- Pointed `CARBON_HOME` to my `wso/wso2iot 3.1.0`

This is what I downloaded only.

Run `iot-server` in folder bin.

After that nothing the system don't give me localhost why?

Is this installation correct for running `wso2iot`?

If not please advise me. Do I need to install something else?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to have java 8 on your system in order to run the WSO2 IoT 3.1.0. Secondly, if you need to run the WSO2 IoT 3.1.0 as a windows services, you need to have jajws 11.03.

Please refer the following [document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Installing+as+a+Windows+Service) for more information

Answer (score 0):

You can download the latest release candidate for WSO2 IoT 3.1.0 from [here](https://github.com/wso2/product-iots/releases/download/v3.1.0-RC3/wso2iot-3.1.0-RC3.zip) unzip it and start the pack in the following order.

- Navigate to `<IOTS_HOME>/bin` and run ./broker.sh
  ./iot-server.sh & 
  ./analytics.sh

Then you can login to the console from - https://localhost:9443/devicemgt

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, to the above reply by jdk7. Make sure that you have JAVA 8. WSO2 IoT Server needs JAVA 8.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/System+Requirements